# How do I return an mysql row based on an arbitrary list of column entries?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a database with product UPC numbers and vendor ID numbers.  It's possible for multiple vendors to supply the same products, so a simple query against UPC can (and often does) return multiple rows.  However, there is a vendor preference list (because vendors sell the same product at different prices), and my goal is to return the product entry from the most preferred vendor.  In short, given five vendors numbered 1 through 5, the preferred vendor list may be $vendors = array(5,3,1,2,4);.  Different users have different preference lists.  Therefore, right now I'm creating the preferred vendor list, looping through queries up to five (actually 83) times, and stopping the first time a query returns a row.  It's very slow.  Is there a single MySQL command that accepts (sorts by) an arbitrary list of column values and, using "LIMIT 1", return only the first found value?

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE upc='123456789123' AND vendor='5';
SELECT * FROM products WHERE upc='123456789123' AND vendor='3';
```

Theoretically becomes something like...

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE upc='12345678123' AND vendor=('5', '3') LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: What exactly you after? you need output from vendor 5 or vendor 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM products WHERE upc='12345678123' AND vendor in ('5', '3')
Order BY 
CASE WHEN Vendor = '5' THEN '1'
WHEN Vendor = '3' THEN '2'
ELSE Vendor END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 SELECT * FROM products WHERE upc='12345678123' AND vendor in ('5', '3') LIMIT 1;
```

See `in` operator in sql, you may directly pass your array list of vendor IDs in to that.